# Windows 10 Insider Preview - Lumia 920, wifi not working after install

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, wifi

Last night I installed the Windows 10 Mobile Insider Preview (Slow) (Build 10.0.10166.0)

Everything seems ok, but when I try enable the wi-fi an error popup is shown (in spanish) that say something like "Unable to do this right now!, Try again in few minutes. If the issue persists, restart the phone and try again".

I restarted the phone few times but the error still there.

Does anybody faced this issue and/or know a workaround that allow me back online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend doing a hard reset after a Windows 10 Insider Preview update. This usually solves a lot of problems that the update process introduces.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, finally as you said, a hard reset was the solution.